# How to create playlist in on audioquery package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making music player in flutter using just audio package.Now I'm doing the playlist part.I'm Done creating the playlist using hive db.but i confused how to Add music in created playlist? Please help.

how to Add music in created playlist? Please help.